# Display the total as 0

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a shopping cart. i am trying to get the total as
   the output but it return as 0 the output should be price * quantity but the result was 0 those are the things that i already tried.   I am trying to create a shopping cart. i am trying to get the total as
   the output but it return as 0 the output should be price * quantity but the result was 0 those are the things that i already tried.

```
    <?php

include 'config.php';

{
    if (isset($_POST["cart"])){

        $field0 = $_POST["field0"];
        $field1 = $_POST["field1"];
        //$field2 = $_POST["field2"];
        $field3 = $_POST["field3"];
        $field4 = $_POST["field4"];
        $field5 = $_POST["field5"];
        $or_qty = $_POST["or_qty"];
        $price = $_POST["price"];

    if (empty($field0)||empty($field1)||empty($field3)||empty($field4)||empty($field5)){
        //echo '<script>alert("Please Complete all the data")</script>';
    }else{
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `template` (`field0`,`field1`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`,`or_qty`) VALUES ('$field0','$field1','$field3','$field4','$field5','$or_qty')");
        //echo '<script>alert("Order is added to cart")</script>';
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    $total = 0;
if ($field0 == 1){
    $total = $total + ($or_qty);
}
    elseif($field0 == 2){
        $total = $total + ($or_qty*$price);
    }
    elseif($field0 == 3){
        $total = $total + ($or_qty*$price);
    }
    elseif($field0 == 4){
        $total = $total + ($or_qty*$price);
    }
    echo number_format($total);
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `product_order` (`total`,`or_Qty`,`price`) VALUES ('$total','$or_qty','$price')");
    ?>
    <!--$total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);-->

    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently.

Comment: `$price = $_POST["price"]` Oh my God! That probably means I can buy your products at any price that I want

Comment: It's an odd thing to have a table with columns named `field0`,`field1`,`field3`,etc

Answer (score 0):

By giving $_POST["cart"] a value and manually setting $field0, $or_qty, and $price, I was able to get $total to equal something other than 0.
If I remove $_POST["cart"]=3;, total is always 0.

I also added some logic to make sure the total is only shown if $_POST["cart"] is set and cleaned up your code a bit.

I think your problem is that $_POST["cart"] isn't set and therefore the rest of the variables are also never set.

Usually $_POST values are set via a form or some other webpage.

[Finally, you should consider using prepared statements to prevent mysql injections.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$_POST["cart"]=3;
    if (isset($_POST["cart"])){

        $field0 = 3;
        $field1 = $_POST["field1"];
        //$field2 = $_POST["field2"];
        $field3 = $_POST["field3"];
        $field4 = $_POST["field4"];
        $field5 = $_POST["field5"];
        $or_qty = 4;
        $price = 0.50;

    if (empty($field0)||empty($field1)||empty($field3)||empty($field4)||empty($field5)){
        //echo '<script>alert("Please Complete all the data")</script>';
    }else{
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `template` (`field0`,`field1`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`,`or_qty`) VALUES ('$field0','$field1','$field3','$field4','$field5','$or_qty')");
        //echo '<script>alert("Order is added to cart")</script>';
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cart</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["cart"])){
        $total = 0;
        if ($field0 == 1){
            $total = $total + ($or_qty);
        }
        elseif($field0 == 2){
            $total = $total + ($or_qty*$price);
        }
        elseif($field0 == 3){
            $total = $total + ($or_qty*$price);
        }
        elseif($field0 == 4){
            $total = $total + ($or_qty*$price);
        }
        echo number_format($total);
        $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `product_order` (`total`,`or_Qty`,`price`) VALUES ('$total','$or_qty','$price')");
    }
    ?>
    <!--$total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);-->
</body>
</html>
```